# Power Query Merging on Null values

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I was very surprised to find out that `Table.NestedJoin` joins columns join on `null`.  This seems like the wrong choice to me, but *the compiler is always right*.  In the example below, `Table1` and `Table2` (which are otherwise identical) are left joined by `ID`.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table1,{"ID"},Table2,{"ID"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table2", {"ID", "Index"}, {"Table2.ID", "Table2.Index"})
in
    #"Expanded Table2"
```

My question is: are there any known best practices to get joins to behave more like standard SQL joins (where `null <> null`).

This is, of course, beyond the simple method of FIND/REPLACE `null` with *special thing that no one could possibly use in arbitrary data...that someone will have inevetably used in arbitrary data*.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Couldn't you filter the second table to exclude Null first?

Comment: http://excel-inside.pro/blog/2018/05/17/comparing-null-values-in-power-query/  The [language specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/A/81A62C9B-04D5-4B6D-B162-D28E4D848552/Power%20Query%20Formula%20Language%20Specification%20(October%202016).pdf) sets null = null as True

Comment: It's not difficult to remove nulls from one table or the other either before or after merging to get the particular result you want. Do you need a more complicated solution?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I'm really trying to avoid death by a thousand paper cuts.  Filter and Find/Replace are certainly available... but it is two steps.  I want find trying to find something within the join specification itself that clearly indicates what I'm doing.  Wishful thinking, perhaps.  I feel like I'm going to have a hard enough time explaining to less technical coworkers that "It works this way in SQL, but this way in Power BI".  Putting it in one place could make it more straightforward to maintain.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all languages behave identically. I'd be surprised if there is a one-step solution.

Comment: the link from @QHarr is broken, here is the new url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-values#null . @Rory's solution looks best. `Table2 = Table.SelectRows( Source2, each [ID] <> null )` , then join on that.